# Is it possible to make gradle resolve ivy dependencies like '5.0.+' in order to get versions like '5.0.0.1.12.24'?

Tags: svn, version, ivy

We are currently rewriting our versioning, which is handled by gradle.

The last number of our version inhibits the svn revision number. When it comes to resolving dependencies, we are using the wildcard `+` on the last number:

```
testCompile 'my.great.company:ProjectName:5.0.0.0.0.+'
```

But this only gets the highest number for the last digit of the version, the revision.

However, if I want the lastest overall version, something like:

```
5.1.2.3.4.25
```

I would like to write it like

```
testCompile 'my.great.company:ProjectName:5.+'
```

I found out, that it is possible to define the version in whatever way you want to (as long as it is UTF-8), but I do not know, if it is possible to resolve the dependency as described above?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it is possible to do this.**

you can define your dependency like

```
testCompile 'my.great.company:ProjectName:5.+'
```

and it will allways take the latest version, that it finds in the specified Ivy repository.

Even

```
testCompile 'my.great.company:ProjectName:5.1.2.+'
```

works and takes the latest version after 5.1.2

The only restriction is, that the `+` has to be on the last digit.